# Как разрешается конфликт изменений при слиянии ветвей?

Tags: git, git-merge

Диспозиция такая:

Есть две ветки. в каждой из них присутствует файл который редактировался (один и тот же).

При слиянии веток что произойдет с этим файлом?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Если кратко: произойдет конфликт слияния (merge conflict) и его нужно будет как-то разрешить.

- Для бинарных файлов: только выбрать версию А или Б (или другие, если octomerge).

Бывает, что бинарные файлы Git воспринимает как текстовые и тогда merge их необратимо портит. Это прежде всего относится к файлам office-форматов.

- Для текстовых файлов: пара вариантов:

#### Вручную разрешить конфликты

После merge в файле появятся куски из обеих сливаемых версий, как-то так:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD  
содержимое файла из первой ветки
======
содержимое файла из второй ветки  
>>>>>>> otherbranch
```

Нужно будет вручную отредактировать конфликтный файл (или файлы), при этом не забывая удалить метки, оставленные Git (`>>>>>>> otherbranch`). Затем:

```
git add conflicting-file-name.txt
git commit -m'merged A and B'
```

#### Выбрать одну из версий файла

Можно явным образом указать: какой файл выбирать. Подходит, только если одна из версий не нужна.

```
git checkout --ours a.txt
git checkout --theirs a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -m "added theirs"
```

---

Сделал вам [тестовый репозиторий](https://github.com/NickVolynkin/git-merge-test), чтобы сразу клонировать и посмотреть, как оно работает.

```
git clone https://github.com/NickVolynkin/git-merge-test.git
cd git-merge-test
git merge otherbranch
open a.txt
```

В файле видны отметки, можете с ним теперь проделать вышеописанные действия.

Подробнее написано в книге [Pro Git на русском](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Ее обязательно нужно прочитать, прежде чем работать со слиянием веток. Фундаментальное понимание процесса ничем не заменить.

Потренироваться с ветвлением и слиянием можно тут: [Learn Git Branching](https://learngitbranching.js.org/).

Comment: как раз сейчас её читаю-по мере работы.просто возникла такая ситуация в голове и заинтересовал вопрос.спасибо,за разъяснения)

Comment: @DarkVss: тренажер (последняя ссылка) очень хорош. Рекомендую его пройти, прежде чем любые действия с branch-rebase-merge делать )

Comment: хорошо) посмотрим

Answer (score 4):

проблемы с мерджем могут возникнуть из-за использования неудобного редактора. Попробуйте сменить Ваш консольный редактор на IDE или специализированный софт для этих нужд

https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux

Nick Volynkin теорию скинул

Comment: о онлайн тренингах упомянули. мануал скинули? С софтом то что не так?

Comment: настоящие мужики мержат руками!

Comment: поэтому я и упомянул об разрешении конфликтов с помощью консольного редактора)