# Почему при слиянии веток затирается часть файла без конфликта?

Tags: git, git-merge, source-tree

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно делать слияние,уже какой день мучаюсь и ничего не получается.Есть ветка в которой я работаю,и хочу получить новые изменения из мастера и слить мастер с текущей веткой, но при слиянии я получаю все что есть на мастере а код над которым я работал в текущей ветке весь затирается.

Подробнее:

В мастере находится один файл index.php в котором всего лишь одна функция index().Так же есть ветка в которой работаю в ней тот же файл index.php но содержит 3 функции. one() two() tree(). После этого я хочу сделать merge мастера в текущую ветку.После данного слияния все функции в рабочей ветке затираются и остается только функция index().

Comment: Опишите поэтапно порядок ваших действий, при котором ваш код оказывается затёрт.

Comment: Делаю сперва Pull на локальный мастер,после чего переключаюсь на другую ветку в которой работаю  и  делаю слияение мастера в текущую ветку,после чего в ветке остается только код мастера,все над чем работал затирается.

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы делаете это через SourceTree? Если сделать это из командной строки, `git` выведет отчёт, что он сделал и почему. Да, я всё ещё не понимаю, что именно вы сделали и как так вышло. Приложите эту последовательность в вопрос. По возможности, и граф последних коммитов. И совсем в идеале, отчёт о тех же действиях в командной строке.

Comment: Да работаю через SourTree.Крастко для примера попытаюсь объяснить что и как.В мастере находится один файл index.php в котором всего лишь одна функция index().Так же есть ветка в которой работаю в ней тот же файл index.php но содержит 3 функции. one() two() tree(). После этого я хочу сделать merge мастера в текущую ветку.После данного слияния все функции в рабочей ветке затираются и остается только функция index().

Comment: Всю связанную с вопросом информацию дописывайте в вопрос. Вы сейчас не дали никакой новой информации. Как расположены коммиты от точки ветвления?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как разрешается конфликт изменений при слиянии ветвей?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437456/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: Лучше всего сделать слияние вручную, через командную строку. Еще добавьте в вопрос результат, выводимый командой `git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate`

Comment: @quaresma89 эти функции one/two/three были дописаны вами в вашей ветке? если нет - то может быть кто-то удалил их в master, мерж проходит корректно, и вливает изменения из мастера в вашу ветку (включая удаление функций)

Comment: слишком длинная переписка :) // cc @quaresma89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, вы работаете в ветке `dev`. Также у вас есть локальная ветка `master` и удалённая ветка `origin/master`. И допустим, удалённый репозиторий подключён как `origin` (так обычно бывает).

Тогда надо сделать так:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

Если после этого в вашей ветке `dev` остался файл в том виде, в котором он у вас в `master`-е, то, вероятно, мастер «ушёл дальше», опережает вашу рабочую ветку и в `master` эти функции (`one()` и `two()`) были удалены теми коммитами, которых нет в `dev`.

Comment: Так и есть я из мастера удалил эти функции чтобы посмотреть каков будет результат!

Comment: Пояивился еще вопрос.Допустим я сделал слияние мастера в рабочую ветку,и решил удалить все функции и слить еще раз в нее мастер,почему при повтором слиянии функции которые есть в мастере не переносятся в рабочую ветку?

Comment: @quaresma89: Пожалуйста, задайте этот вопрос как [новый вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @quaresma89: ответ я уже знаю, пока его как раз напишу ) Ответьте мне, как опубликуете вопрос )

Comment: Опубликовал. Скинуть ссылку на вопрос или как поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Прошел весь этот путь на Atlassian Sourcetree с тестовым репозиторием.

```
https://github.com/NickVolynkin/git-merge-test
```

Вот у нас есть две ветки, обе расходятся с момента коммита. В обеих изменен один и тот же файл (в данном случае это index.php).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем ту ветку **в которую** будем мерджить и жмем кнопочку.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Появляется диалог, в котором нужно выбрать коммит, который мы будем мерджить в нашу ветку. Выбираем master.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Появляется сообщение о том, что есть конфликты слияния и нам придется их разрешать. Если у вас такого сообщения не было — это подтверждает гипотезу PashaPash о том, что функции `one() two() three()` были удалены в одном из коммитов, прямым предком которых является ваша рабочая ветка.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь конфликты нужно разрешить, вручную поправив документ. Подробнее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437458/181472

Когда они разрешены, починенный файл нужно добавить кнопкой ADD:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А потом сделать коммит.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам предложат написать сообщение коммита.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Готово, слияние выполнено.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/ очень наглядно, думаю многие вопросы с git исчезнут

Comment: Уже много статей читал и вроде разобрался,но на практике вот такое происходит.