# Failed to sync this branch due to unmerged files

Tags: git, git-merge

Раньше никогда не работал более чем с одной веткой и вот столкнулся с проблемой. Создал ветку и закомитил туда изменения, затем отправил *pull request*. Теперь когда я делаю коммит на ветке `master` и синхронизируюсь (все это делаю через github), выдает ошибку "*Failed to sync this branch due to unmerged files*"

Пробовал использовать `git mergetool` и еще кое-что, что нашел на форумах, но получилась полная каша.. Откатился на предыдущий коммит через `git reset --hard xxxxxxxx`.

Что мне теперь делать? `git status` выдает подсказки как на скриншоте. Нужно использовать `git add` для выделенных красным файлов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как разрешается конфликт изменений при слиянии ветвей?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437456/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что в категории Unmerged paths (выделено красным), придется мерджить вручную. В эту категорию попадают те файлы, которые были изменены в обеих ветках после того, как они разошлись.

Не могу разобрать имена файлов. Если там код — то можно составить из двух версий одну. Если бинарники — то только выбрать одну из версий. Похоже, четвертой строкой там сцена `.unity`. К сожалению, вам придется выбрать один из вариантов сцены и вручную повторить все изменения из второго.

Когда все конфликты разрулите — `git add -u` и `git commit`.

Еще там два каких-то новых `.cs файла`. Если они не временные, то наверняка их тоже нужно добавить `git add --all` и закоммитить.

Подробнее тут: [Как разрешается конфликт изменений при слиянии ветвей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437456/181472)

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось