# Контроль версий для файлов MS Office, Libre Office и других XML-based

Tags: git, git-config

Хочу хранить в репозитории Git файлы из офисных пакетов вроде MS Office или Libre Office.

- Возможны ли какие-то проблемы?
- Как правильно организовать хранение?
- Можно ли производить слияние (merge) этих файлов средствами Git?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Возможны ли какие-то проблемы?

Есть ряд форматов данных, которые внутри себя устроены как папки/архивы, содержащие текст (xml) и бинарные данные. [Список XML-based форматов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:XML-based_standards) просто огромен, приведу одни из самых популярных:

- [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument): `.odt`, `.ods`, `.odp` и прочие.
- [OpenOffice.org XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org_XML): `.sxw`, `.sxc`, `.sxi` и прочие.
- [Open Packaging Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions) `.docx`, `.xlsx`, `.pptx` и прочие.

Git может распознавать такие файлы как текст. Тогда он

- Начнет приводить к общему виду окончания строк,
- При слиянии ветвей соберет один документ из двух, рассчитывая на дальнейшую ручную правку.

То и другое испортит файл почти необратимым образом.

Из документации Git: [gitattributes, "Marking files as binary"](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

> Git usually guesses correctly whether a blob contains text or binary data by examining the beginning of the contents. However, sometimes you may want to override its decision, either because a blob contains binary data later in the file, or because the *content, while technically composed of text characters, is opaque to a human reader*.

### Как правильно организовать хранение?

В корневой директории проекта нужно создать файл  `.gitattributes` (или отредактировать, если уже есть). В него добавить следущую строку — для каждого расширения файлов, которое там будет храниться:

```
*.<расширение> binary
```

Пример:

```
*.docx    binary
*.xlsx    binary
*.odt    binary
```

Таким образом вы явно отмечаете, что файлы с данным расширением необходимо обрабатывать как бинарные. В бинарном файле Git никогда не будет заменять окончания строк (т.к. для него это теперь не CR и LF, а просто байты).

### Можно ли производить слияние (merge) этих файлов средствами Git?

Если `.gitattributes` настроен правильно, то можно производить слияние веток, содержащих такие файлы.

При слиянии документ не будет испорчен, но и объединить содержимое двух файлов в один автоматически не получится. Однако, [PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash) подсказывает, что [в MS Office есть специальный инструмент для слияния файлов](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-and-combine-documents-in-Word-2007-420236df-c0a1-4f05-8962-03c7a1827074).

После того, как вы вручную собрали из двух документов один (или выбрали одну из версий), [нужно проиндексировать изменения и подтвердить их коммитом, чтобы завершить слияние](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437458/181472).

Comment: у ms office есть встроенный diff/2-way merge (и вроде даже 3-way merge) для документов, может быть стоит про него упомянуть?

Comment: @PashaPash: правда? Спасибо, я не знал. Добавлю.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-and-combine-documents-in-Word-2007-420236df-c0a1-4f05-8962-03c7a1827074 - я точно знаю что во времена svn были скрипты для мержа, но для git не нашел ничего готового

Comment: @PashaPash: спасибо, добавил ссылку. Проверил на своем Word — действительно, есть merge.