# Проблема с git xlsx clrf

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-config

Клонирую репозиторий (там есть файл `rename_spreadsheets.xlsx`), сразу поле клона делаю `git status` и получаю результат

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   rename_spreadsheets.xlsx

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Нагуглил что дело может быть в CRLF и LF, но если закомитить файл с `core.autocrlf input` то файл не открывается и считается поврежденным, даже если потом включить `core.autocrlf true`

Если сделать `git checkout rename_spreadsheets.xlsx`, то ничего не произойдет, файл так и останется "измененным"

Тестировал на Linux и macOS.

Comment: Кратко: отметьте их как бинарные (нетекстовые) в `.gitattributes` и Git перестанет менять окончания строк. [Контроль версий для файлов MS Office, Libre Office и других XML-based](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448603/181472)