# ошибка в файле csproj - не удалось загрузить файл проекта. Знак "<", шестнадцатеричное значение 0x3C, не может стоять в начале имени.,

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-mvc

При обновлении проекта, выдает след. ошибку в файле csproj:

**не удалось загрузить файл проекта. Знак "<", шестнадцатеричное значение 0x3C, не может стоять в начале имени., строка 251, позиция 2.**

В чем собственно проблема с символом?

Это фрагмент кода. HEAD - 251 строка:

```
    <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <Compile Include="Models\Home\DownloadProgramModel.cs" />
=======
    <Compile Include="Models\Authorization\SignInModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\FunctionBrain\IndexModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\HealthPanel\EditProfileModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\HealthPanel\IndexModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Home\DictionaryTermsModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Home\ExampleDecryptionModel.cs" />
>>>>>>> remotes/origin/Branch_EditProfile
    <Compile Include="Models\Home\IndexModel.cs" />
```

Comment: Вы начали и не закончили слияние ветвей в Git. Подробнее тут: [Как разрешается конфликт изменений при слиянии ветвей?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А как Вы думаете, `<<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======` и т.п. в файле проекта это нормально? Ваш проект нуждается в законченном слиянии, которое, видимо, было начато и не закончено. Закончите слияние(выбрав нужные версии строк) и ошибка пропадёт.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать