# Соединение двух ветвей на github

Tags: git, github, git-merge

У меня есть две ветви на github.

Первая master - на ней старый код, и вторая develop - на ней новый код (последние изменения).

Как соединить (merge) эти две ветви, чтобы на master оказался новый код?

Comment: Как пробовали это сделать? В чем возникла проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Merge develop and master branches](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498802/merge-develop-and-master-branches)

Comment: Как написано в любой книжке про git, так и сделать

Comment: Мне не жалко - я и тут напишу: `git checkout master`; `git merge develop`

Answer (score 2):

1. переключитесь на ветку, **в** которую собираетесь делать слияние:

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   ```
2. и слейте с той веткой, **из** которой собираетесь делать слияние:

   ```
   $ git merge develop
   ```
3. если возникнут конфликты при слиянии — [внесите необходимые исправления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437458/178576).
4. при необходимости — отправьте изменения в удалённый репозиторий:

   ```
   $ git push
   ```