# Переключиться на коммит и продолжить работу с него, а потом вернуться к старой ветке

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-branch, git-push

Для перехода к работе с одним из старых коммитов, я пользовался такой схемой:

```
git checkout -b имя-новой-ветки aaaaaa

 (wt)
 (i)
  A - B - C - D
  ↑           ↑
 new       master
(HEAD)
```

Взятой из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83).

Но теперь мне нужно слиться с веткой `master`, так чтобы оказаться после коммита `D`, и придти в вот такое состояние. Так как работа все таки ведется в ветке `master`.

```
     ---------- M
   /             \
  A - B - C - D - H
                  ↑
                master
                (HEAD)
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Коммит `М` в вашей ветке фичи сделан или в `master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы всё правильно сделали.
Предположим, вы только что сделали новый коммит `F`<sup>*</sup> в ветке `feature`:

```
            (HEAD)
             new
              ↓
    --------- F
   /           
  A - B - C - D 
              ↑
            master
```

<sup>* – не использую здесь букву M, чтобы она досталась merge-коммиту.</sup>

Самое простое —  переключиться на ветку `master` и дать команду на слияние (мерж, merge) в неё вашей ветки.

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

Если одни и те же строки менялись как в  `F`, так и в цепочке `B`, `C`, `D`, то будет конфликт слияния. [Его нужно будет разрешить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437456/181472), вручную выбрав нужные строки из обоих вариантов.

Результат:

- В `master` появится новый мерж-коммит с двумя предками: `D` и `F`.
- Ветка `new` останется нетронутой.

```
             new
              ↓
    --------- F -
   /             \
  A - B - C - D - M
                  ↑
                master
                (HEAD)
```

---

Loading...

Comment: Вечером допишу про `rebase`. Напомните, если что.

Comment: Ок спасибо. А если я не хочу разрешать в ручную я же как-то могу сказать гиту что в конфликте D и F, F - всегда права?

Comment: @Павел  `git merge -s theirs` https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies

Comment: @Павел но это рискованная практика — вы можете иметь в виду одно место, а git за вас молча исправит ещё и другие. Надёжнее руками порешать конфликты.

Comment: UPD: нет, не этим вечером, сил не осталось. )

Answer (score 1):

Запутанно однако. Если вы хотите сделать какие-либо изменения на базе опредeленного коммита, то можно создать новую ветку с коммита, сделать нужные изменения, сделать коммит в ветку а потом просто слить ветку с master.