# Как сделать слияние в Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

У меня есть ветка Two и ветка First.

Я создал ветку Two из ветки First.

И после правок я хочу залить ветку Two обратно в ветку First

Как это сделать средствами Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Переключиться на ветку First
2. В меню веток выбрать ветку Two
3. В её меню выбрать `merge`

Comment: А это в Local или Remote. Из за этого у меня путаница

Comment: @xTIGRx, это будет локально. Чтобы в ремот отправить изменения - надо `push` после слияния сделать - отправится `merge-commit`

Comment: Тогда еще 1 вопрос.
Когда создаю ветку надо создавать мне по нажатии на "New Branch" или в Remote "Checkout as New local Branch"?

Comment: @xTIGRx, всё зависит от ваших целей. Первый вариант создаст локально новую ветку. Её не будет в ремоте, её надо будет туда пушить. Второй вариант - это получить локальную копию существующей ремот ветки

Answer (score 5):

<s>[Вылить воду из чайника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/879eb5f3-f8b5-404f-bfad-b85d6f6caf1d/view-source)</s>

Открыть консоль с помощью <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>, чем свести задачу к предыдущей:

```
git checkout First
git merge Two
```

В процессе слияния может случиться конфликт изменений. Его нужно будет разрешить: [Как разрешается конфликт изменений при слиянии ветвей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437456/181472)

Если консоль говорит, что не знает про git – это наверняка cmd.exe. Замените его на git bash по инструкции: [Embed Git bash in PyCharm as external tool and work with it in PyCharm window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180050/2790048).

Чтобы отправить результат на удалённый сервер (remote):

```
# в первый раз
git push -u origin master
# потом
git push
```