# Сравнение 2 проектов на Andorid

Tags: android, git

Имеется:

1. разработчик приложения (разраб1) - главный разработчик который продает исходный код приложения на Android и в дальнейшем делайет апдейты приложения выпуская новые версии
2. я (разраб2) - я купил у разраба1 его приложение и допиливаю его.

Проблема: я(разраб2) купил приложение версии 1.0, создал с ним репозиторий в гите и месяц допиливал. После чего я вижу, что разраб 1 выкатил версию приложения 1.1 с новыми фишками (просто rar архив со всеми файлами). Я хочу эти фишки добавить и в свое приложение.

Вопрос - как правильно просмотреть все новые фишки приложения от разраба1 и по желанию внести часть из них в свое приложение?

Смотрел есть проги типа winmerge, KDiff3, Beyond Comapre, Araxis Merge. В правильном направлении я смотрю, или может надо смотреть в сторону Git Fork? В гите не особо шарю, объясните как лучше сделать. Или может стандартными средствами Android Studio как-то можно обойтись?

Comment: может попробовать переключиться в гите на 1.0 (без ваших изменений), создать ветку, скопировать версию 1.1 и закомитить, и эту новую ветки и мержить с вашей основной, выбирая что вам нужно, а что нет?

Answer (score 1):

что (для вас) очень плохо в описанной ситуации — это то, что разработчик предоставил весь набор изменений одним куском: наверняка ведь им реализована была не одна «фишка», а несколько, и многие из них наверняка состояли из нескольких **взаимосвязанных** правок разных файлов.

посмотреть, что вообще изменилось между версиями 1.0 и 1.1 можно, например, с помощью программы [*diff*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff):

```
$ diff -Nuar каталог-1.0 каталог-1.1
```

где `каталог-1.0` и `каталог-1.1` — каталоги, в которые распакованы исходники версий 1.0 и 1.1

вы сможете увидеть, какие файлы (и как) были изменены, какие добавлены, какие удалены. хуже в случае если файл был переименован: программа отобразит это как удаление одного файла (старого) и создание другого (нового).

теперь вам надо вычленить из всего этого набора изменений нужные вам «фишки». это творческая задача, никакой искусственный интеллект (на данном этапе его развития) вам тут не поможет.

следующий этап — внесение этих «фишек» в ваше хранилище.

1. создайте (если ещё не создан) указатель («ветка/branch» в программе *git* является указателем на коммит) с именем, например, `v1.0`, указывающий на первый ваш коммит (которым вы внесли в своё хранилище исходники версии 1.0):

   ```
   $ git checkout -b v1.0 хэш-первого-коммита
   ```
2. (отсюда начинается рекурсия) внесите изменения, которые вы вычленили из присланных исходников, и идентифицировали как «фишка номер эн», закоммитьте их.
3. теперь попробуйте влить это изменение в вашу рабочую версию.

   1. сделайте текущим ваш рабочий указатель (например, `master`):

      ```
      $ git checkout master
      ```
   2. наложите изменения из указателя `v1.0` (коммит не будет сделан благодаря опции `--no-commit`):

      ```
      $ git merge --no-commit v1.0
      ```

      если возникли конфликты: [Как разрешается конфликт изменений при слиянии ветвей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437456/178576)
   3. протестируйте вашу программу: убедитесь, что ничего не сломалось, и появилась новая «фишка», которую вы и переносили.
   4. если что-то пошло не так, у вас два пути: либо «допилить» данную «фишку» до рабочего состояния, либо вообще от неё отказаться.
   5. когда решите, что всё в порядке и можно добавлять, просто сделайте коммит, если решили отказаться — сделайте

      ```
      $ git reset --hard
      ```

      в дополнение см., например: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/178576)
   6. опять переключитесь на `v1.0`:

      ```
      $ git checkout v1.0
      ```
   7. если на предыдущем шаге вы выбрали «отказаться» — возвратитесь к предыдущему коммиту в истории (не взлетевшая «фишка» таким образом канет в лету):

      ```
      $ git reset --hard HEAD^
      ```
   8. повторите действия рекурсивно, начиная с шага 2, для всех остальных «фишек».